# Visual Studio 2012 jQuery Mobile data attribute intellisense

Tags: jquery-mobile, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Is there a Visual Studio 2012 plugin that will provide intellisense for jQuery Mobile data attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Though it is not possible but there is workaround to get this working through manual steps.

Haven't tried these myself but you can give it a try.

[AngularJS Intellisense in Visual Studio 2012](http://madskristensen.net/post/angularjs-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2012)

Hopefully it helps.

Cheers !!